# Аутентификация Windows

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2

Мне нужна аутентификация Windows в качестве одного из способов аутентификации. Все методы лежат под JWT токеном. То есть не важно, какой способ я выбрал, в итоге аутентификация будет по токену. Так вот, аутентификация Windows должна проходить только если пользователь находится в домене. При этом запрашивать учетные данные она не должна.

Делаю так

```
services.Configure<IISOptions>(iis =>
{
    iis.AuthenticationDisplayName = "Windows";
    iis.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
    iis.ForwardClientCertificate = true;
});
```

Не работает. Может ли вообще это так (как мне нужно) работать? Если да, то как настроить?

**UPD:**

Не работает только с других машин, находящихся в домене. Если пытаюсь с той машины, где запущено приложение, то все норм.

Вообще эта аутентификация виндовая - сплошная магия. При аутентификации с локальной машины подсасывается заголовок "MS-ASPNETCORE-TOKEN". Откуда он берется, непонятно. В средствах разработчика в браузере я его не вижу. Получив такой запрос, выполняется `Challenge("Windows")`, который возвращает 401, но браузер при этом не выдает ошибку. Вообще не похоже, что ответ возвращается клиенту, но запрос выполняется снова. И теперь уже мы имеем виндовые claims, которые берутся из нового заголовка, который теперь появился в реквесте MS-ASPNETCORE-WINAUTHTOKEN o_O

То, что данные пользователя берутся при помощи последнего заголовка, я подсмотрел в исходниках asp net core. Но откуда берется этот заголовок? Что вообще происходит? Помогите разобраться! :(